# Cant assign found item to variable as array

Tags: java, mongodb

```
 db.getSiblingDB("pilates").ball.find({ "list.Barcode.":  "80196061999242"})
```

When , i run this query, it brings this document.

```
    { 

            "Brand" : "Givi", 
"list" : [
    {

        "Barcode" : [
            "8019606199942"
]
}
..
    }
]
    .
    ...
    .

        }
```

but when i run this

```
     db.getSiblingDB("pilates").ball.find({ "list.Barcode.":  "80196061999242"})  .forEach(function(x){


print("m "+x.list.[0].Barcode);})
```

it gives this output

```
m undefined
```

or for this

```
print("m "+x.list.(0).Barcode);})
```

it gives this

```
is not a function :
@(shell):4:16
DBQuery.prototype.forEach@src/mongo/shell/query.js:501:1
@(shell):1:1
```

for this

```
 print("m "+x.list.Barcode);})
```

gives this

```
m undefined
```

for this
  print("m "+x.$.Barcode);})

gives this

```
$ is undefined :
@(shell):4:3
DBQuery.prototype.forEach@src/mongo/shell/query.js:501:1
@(shell):1:1
```

Why cant it get?

Comment: Please do us a favor and properly format your question. It's a pain to read some of the code snippets atm. Also, all your code seems to be JavaScript, are you sure you correctly used the Java tag?

Comment: Aside from that needing to be `list[0]` it's not clear if you either have a typo with `"list.Barcode."` in the query with the trailing **dot** `"."` or whether your data is represented incorrectly. If that is the actual query being run. If it's the actual query then that would be `x.list[0]['Barcode.'][0]` to include the "dot" in the key name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*List* ins't an object but an array, then you need to do this:

```
print("m "+x.list[0].Barcode[0]);
```

Basically, to remove the `.`. And `Barcode` is an array too.